# Acesso simultâneo API Rest

Tags: php, concorrência

Tenho uma aplicação PHP que recebe json de uma outra aplicação e os grava no banco de dados MySQL.
     Antes de gravar os dados, eu verifico no banco pra ver se o registro já não foi gravado anteriormente. 
     Porém, ao verificar o banco de dados agora a tarde, me deparo com dois registros iguais. O que pode ter acontecido? Será que a aplicação cliente foi tão rápida e antes que a primeira fosse gravada no banco a segunda também estava sendo processada? Como posso me proteger disso?
     A configuração do meu Apache está padrão.

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os gerenciados de banco de dados conseguem evitar o acesso múltiplo. É claro que é possível que após um select um insert de outra consulta seja feito. Para torna-la mais confiável pode-se fazer uma transação select seguido de insert. E outra, se dois registros não podem ser iguais devia ser uma restrição no banco de dados.

Comment: Boa observação. Agora que você falou, que eu me liguei em deixar único o número do registro. Eu coloquei o id e esqueci do número. Sobre o transaction eu realmente não sabia que poderia usar com um select e um insert. Atualmente uso apenas no insert pois escrevo em mais de uma tabela. Amanhã implementarei isso logo cedo.